# Django: is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

I'm use Django 1.8

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'app.views.login', name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'app.views.logout', name='logout'),
    url(r'^main/$',  'app.views.main', { 'templatename': 'main.html' }, name="main"),
    url(r'^dffr/(?P<page_name>\w+)/$', 'app.views.ajax', name="ajax_page")
)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def ajax(request, page_name, **kwargs):
    # some random context
    ...
    return HttpResponse(return_str)
```

main.html

```
...
{% url 'ajax_page:page_name' %}
...
```

It's get me Exception Type: NoReverseMatch:
'ajax_page' is not a registered namespace

I'm want to get app with dynamic links /dffr/{some_text}/ in this urls.py
Why I must create and register new namespace and create new urls.py for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you would need to do is the following:

```
...
{% url 'ajax_page' page_name='some_page_name' %}
...
```

The url function refers to your registered url names, not the name of your views.

This is explained in the Django url template tag documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: Right, except the URL name is "ajax_page".

Comment: It's not worked too. Reverse for 'dffr' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'page_name': 'some_page_name'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Jorge Silva, It's work. Thanks! And second question: how I can formular parametr page_name by js in frontend?

Comment: Hi Jorge, Am trying to use one of your git project (Django+rethinkdb chat using tornado).. Facing some error, could you pls have a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34385066/tornado-doesnt-recognize-djangos-installed-apps-while-starting-it ?